# How can I collect flow IP protocol from SDN Switch, am using Ryu controller

Tags: python, sdn, openflow, openvswitch, ryu

I am trying to collect flow statistics from SDN switch using the Ryu controller. I need a code on how I can collect ip_protocol from each flow using OFPFLOWSTATREQUEST AND REPLY HANDLER and save in a CSV FILE.

This is the code I used:

```
def _protocol(self, dpid, flows):
       
        for flow in flows:
           m = {}
           for i in flow.match.items():
               key = list(i)[0]  # match key
               val = list(i)[1]  # match value
               if key == "ip_proto":
                   protocol = val
        return protocol
```

I got this error message after running the code:

```
File "/home/ai/SDN/daapp.py", line 780, in flow_stats_reply_handler
    protocol  = self._protocol(dpid, gflows[dpid])
  File "/home/ai/SDN/daapp.py", line 458, in _protocol
    return protocol
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'protocol' referenced before assignment
```

Answer (score 0):

It may consider the protocol in return to be the same as the protocol to which the _protocol output is to be placed. When returning, consider another name for the protocol to solve the problem.

```
protocol  = self._protocol(dpid, gflows[dpid])

def _protocol(self, dpid, flows):
       
        for flow in flows:
           m = {}
           for i in flow.match.items():
               key = list(i)[0]  # match key
               val = list(i)[1]  # match value
               if key == "ip_proto":
                   prtcl = val
        return prtcl
```